# Matlab Data Cursor on grayscale image showing three channels

Tags: image, matlab

I have a grayscale uint8 image:

```
I = ones(100,100) * 50;
I = uint8(I);
imshow(I);
```

Now If I try to read a pixel value with the "Data Cursor" it shows instead the RGB value of the gray pixel.

Is there any way to get the gray 0...255 value with data cursor?

Comment: I think it's generally not possible on current monitors to display luminance data, they can only show RGB values, hence if you want to pick the color with the mouse it will provide an RGB value. You could convert it back with a function.

Comment: For monitor I agree with you, but matlab should be able to display within a simple label the true uint8 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be displayed as the "Index" value when you use the data cursor e.g. "Index: 50".

My data cursor box looks like this:

```
X: 63 Y: 43
Index: 50
RGB: 0, 0, 0
```